# Skyrim crashes as soon as I boot up into the menu. How do I fix this?

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

Whenever I boot up Skyrim, it crashes as soon as it reaches the main menu with no dialog or anything. I thought this was related to my using dual monitors somehow, but I disconnected the other monitor and the game still crashed. I tried running the game in different resolutions, both full-screen and windowed, at various quality settings; no dice. My computer does meet the minimum requirements to play Skyrim.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: It's terrible how this crap is acceptable. How can a game be released and have this kind of bug there so widely among the players. I shouldn't have to change my **audio quality** for a single game, no matter how good it is.

Answer (score 7):

I fixed this issue ultimately by configuring my Sound output device and changing the default format of sound output quality in shared mode. To do this in Windows 7, I went through the following windows:

> Control Panel > Sound > (right-click on sound output device(e.g. speakers), properties > 
>   Advanced

Here, I changed the Default Format to 24 bit,  48000 Hz (Studio Quality). After changing this and clicking Apply, Skyrim worked fine on the next startup. According to hyper_gateway, you don't have to set the sound quality that low; for example, 24 bits, 96000hz will still work.

Comment: I have the same issue; however, it still works @ 24 bits, 96000Hz (studio quailty). The sound quality don't have to set down that low :)

Comment: 24 bit 192000 Hz doesn't work, 24 bit 96000 Hz does (@my system, Win7 64 bit).