# Are there crash logs for Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I have crashed twice in a row while mixing healing potions.

Is there a log I can go look at to see what I am doing that is causing the crash?  (Or do I just need to lay off the potions for a while?)

Comment: I find that my client crashes more if I have the Steam shift-tab Web Browser open. That said, Bethesda is notorious for very sparse logfiles when it comes to crashes and whatnot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\GameOverlayUI.exe.log` you will find this helpful message:

> Fri Nov 25 04:11:22 2011 UTC - Generating new string page texture 2730: 128x256, total string texture memory is 393.22 KB
>   Fri Nov 25 04:56:43 2011 UTC - **Detected possibly crashed/killed game, exiting**
>   Fri Nov 25 04:56:43 2011 UTC - Shutting down overlay

There is a dialog in Steam to allow you to pass arguments to the game. It could be that one of them is for debug mode.

I found that it would start crashing at a savepoint more often if there were a lot of dead bodies scattered around. I went into the console and marked them for deletion, and then it got past that point. I also managed to delete a small lake in the process.

But it still crashes.

Comment: A lake?! You vandal! ;)

Answer (score 7):

Go to `My Documents/My Games/Skyrim` and open up `Skyrim.ini`.

Then add this:

```
[Papyrus]
fPostLoadUpdateTimeMS=500.0
bEnableLogging=1
bEnableTrace=1
bLoadDebugInformation=1
```

If the section `[Papyrus]` already exists, then you might add it without the section identifier. Next time you start the game you should see a new folder called `"logs"` inside that folder. And there is another folder called `"scripts"` and inside that 4 new log files.

Comment: The Papyrus scripting engine isn't involved during potion crafting, at least without mods. This *does* produce a log, yes, but it's not a log that would have anything to do with the OP's crashes.

Comment: You can't say that without trying ;). But I think it is a better answer than the existing one, which does not provide a solution to the answer.